# Put chrome in presentation Mode, but not maximized

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like to put one window of chrome into "presentation mode" (no ui elements, omnibox, etc), but not maximized.  Is that possible, and if, so, how?  Chrome on Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Is this for Google Slides? Other applications?

Comment: Actually for Pandora, but I've often wanted it for other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Picture in Picture Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-viewer/efaagmolahogmekmnmkigonhfcdiemnl)** Google Chrome extension might do the job for you.

---

**Setup**

- Go to  [chrome://flags/#enable-panels](http://chrome://flags/#enable-panels) and enable panels
- Relaunch Chrome

**Use**

*Assuming the web application you're using has an option to go full screen, or go into presentation mode*

- Navigate to a website of your choice
- Activate the Picture in Picture Viewer extension

  - This should open the website in a panel
- From within the panel, toggle the presentation mode for the website you're on
- (Optional) Resize the panel to suit your needs

Comment: It still has the title bar, and f11 (presenttion mode) doens't appear to do anything, but it's 95% of what I wanted.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to hear, and you're right. The title bar persists and the F11 doesn't do anything. This extension works well for websites that have some option to trigger the full screen from the page itself.